# The certificate for itr-links.stackoverflow.email has expired

Tags: bug, status-completed, email, ssl, newsletter

I wanted to change my email address and clicked the link in a newsletter I received, but the server had an expired certificate (roughly 20 hours ago). Shouldn't be a big issue to renew :)

[image: Expired certificate information]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That certificate was being managed by a 3rd party and has now been renewed. When we implemented CAA records we didn't include Amazon which prevented the certificate from automatically renewing.

Comment: I assume Amazon is now included? ;-) Seeing your update that this has been completed, I've gone ahead and added the "completed" tag to the bug report (i.e., the question). Not sure if you have the privileges to do this, despite being staff, since you don't have full mod privileges here. Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: Correct, because the certificate was managed by someone else it took some digging to identify the CAA as the culprit. After that it was pretty quick to make changes to the [CAA record](https://caatest.co.uk/stackoverflow.email). Also noted on updating the tag in the future.